# SBS 2003 Distribution Group not showing up in Active Directory, but it still works

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2003, groups

Under the "MyBusiness" object in Active Directory we have our "Users" folder where I can see all our users as well as all our distribution groups -- except one particular group. Let's call it groupx@ourdomain.com

I can email this distribution group from outside the domain -- and it goes to the recipients, but I cannot find this group anywhere in AD. It's not in the distribution groups, security groups, or any of the other groups under the server tree.

Is there anywhere else I can look besides AD? I just need to modify the group to add another member, but it's not showing up anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipient object *has* to be in the Active Directory. There's no other place that Exchange gets delivery information from. Unless you're using some kind of "front end" email delivery service (Google Postini, etc) that has its own "Group" constructs there *has* to be an Active Directory group.

- Open "Active Directory Users and Computers" and right-click the "Saved Queries" node in the tree in the left pane
- In the "New Query" window specify a name that you like for the "Name" and click the "Define Query..." button
- In the "Find Users, Contacts, and Groups" dialog change the "Find" drop-down to "Exchange Recipients", click "OK" to return to the "New Query" dialog, and click "OK" to save the new query

You will then be able to expand the "Saved Queries" node in the left pane and view all the Exchange recipients in your organization. Since it's SBS you probably don't have a large number and the query should display all of them.

Comment: That worked! And the distribution group is listed under "distribution groups" just like it should be. Yet my distribution groups folder is empty. I wonder why *NONE* of my distribution groups show up in that folder?